# How can I use arithmetic operators (+, * etc.) on custom classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class, operators

Consider this code, where I define a class called `Thing`:

```
 1 class Thing{
 2     public:
 3         int things;
 4         int stuff;
 5 };
 6
 7 int main(){
 8     Thing foo, bar;
 9     foo + bar;
10     return 0;
11 }
```

This question concerns line `9`. Trying to apply the `+` operator between objects which aren't `int` or `float` etc. raises an error, as expected:

`no match for 'operator+' in 'foo + bar'`

So here's my question. What do I need to do to the definition of `Thing`  in order to make the operation `Thing + Thing = valid output`?

For example, `foo + bar = foo.things + foo.stuff + bar.things + bar.stuff`.

Comment: Google "Operator overloading"

Comment: What are you trying to do? You haven't told us. Your examples imply that you mean for `foo + bar` to exist on the LHS of an assignment; do you intend to perform an assignment to a temporary (why?) or to tie `foo` and `bar` together (wrong operator bub)? Can you provide a _concrete_ example of your desired usage?

Comment: The intention is to make `foo + bar` into a valid operation, which doesn't raise an error. The intention is ambiguous. The operation could return an `int`, a new `Thing`, or any other type.